# The crate "pallet-contracts-rpc" does not exists for the branch "polkadot-v0.9.31". Is there any replacement?

Tags: polkadot, smart-contract, contracts

Branch(polkadot-v0.9.31)
https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/polkadot-v0.9.31/frame/contracts

Branch(polkadot-v0.9.30)
https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/polkadot-v0.9.30/frame/contracts/rpc

Since for the branch "polkadot-v0.9.30" the pallet-contracts-rpc was there. I would like to upgrade my outer node file rpc.rs to accommodate the branch "polkadot-v0.9.31". please.

I tried to search in the release notes but I was not able to find anything about this.

Cheers,

Comment: Better to ask repo related questions in the related repos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked [this PR](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/12358)?

I think that checking the files it changed you'll be able to update accordingly.

Comment: In this case, it would be nice to be reflected in the documentation here.[Update the outer node](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/work-with-pallets/contracts-pallet/#update-the-outer-node). Cheers,

Comment: Agree...if you made it and got time, please feel free to open a PR to update that doc =)

Comment: That would be a very good idea. But the real problem is the documentation is not associated with a CI/CD pipeline in which "tags" that documentation to a release version. If we just perform individual ad hoc corrections will increase confusion to new people that want to use Substrate/Polkadot.

Comment: On another Note: don't use semver if 0.0.x increments introduce breaking Changes